# HTML unordered list formatting

Tags: html

How can I format the unordered list in HTML to look like below?

- Item 1 - This is a description of
                the first item

Comment: You can achieve this by using flexbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method.

**Update**

Since, we have added `display: flex` to the li, its default display style got interrupted. So, we can use a workaround using the pseudo elements as I have updated the snippet

```css
ul {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

li {
  display: flex;
}

li::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.title {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.desc {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="title">Title - </span>
        <span class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis magnam facilis aut quos officiis. Blanditiis, facilis itaque. Reiciendis a sapiente nulla qui dolorum, magnam accusamus, sit perspiciatis officia quisquam autem!</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="title">Title - </span>
        <span class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis magnam facilis aut quos officiis. Blanditiis, facilis itaque. Reiciendis a sapiente nulla qui dolorum, magnam accusamus, sit perspiciatis officia quisquam autem!</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="title">Title - </span>
        <span class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis magnam facilis aut quos officiis. Blanditiis, facilis itaque. Reiciendis a sapiente nulla qui dolorum, magnam accusamus, sit perspiciatis officia quisquam autem!</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried this solution but after doing this the bullet points of my list are missing.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the bullet points also, if this satisfy your requirement, please accept the answer

Comment: The improved answer looks good. Will try it. Thank you for your efforts :)